# Netbeans 8.0 maven does not show the newest dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans, dependencies

Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 created a new maven project.

This is a brand new project so there are no previous installed dependencies

Trying to add spring dependencies but netbeans only show older versions.

For example [image]

When search the repository it should be 4.0.x  How do I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reason unknown. You need to type

```
'org.springframwork'
```

To yield the newest version.

Any thing like the following will not work

```
'spring',
'springframework'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even thought it might be a new project I imagine your .m2 cache still has all the old version. I'm not sure how NetBeans builds that screen, but if it's based on your cache rather than what's on central you won't see the newer versions until maven pulls them in

--EDIT--

To manually add the dependency go to [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) and search for the dependency on Spring you need, then copy-paste the generate pom dependency entry into your pom.xml then update your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> Only 1024 of 81415 results shown. Consider narrowing your search

The index search returns the results in fairly random order, so even though Netbeans tries to give you a grouped view, there will be holes because some versions were not included in the 1024 results shown.

A limited number of results is shown for performance reasons. AFAIK.